# How to know when the Promise is actually resolved in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

When we are using Promise in nodejs, given a Promise p, we can't know when the Promise p is actually resolved by logging the currentTime in the "then" callback.

To prove that, I wrote the test code below (using CoffeeScript):

```
# the procedure we want to profile
getData = (arg) ->
    new Promise (resolve) ->
        setTimeout ->
            resolve(arg + 1)
        , 100

# the main procedure
main = () ->
    beginTime = new Date()
    console.log beginTime.toISOString()
    getData(1).then (r) ->
        resolveTime = new Date()
        console.log resolveTime.toISOString()
        console.log resolveTime - beginTime
    cnt = 10**9
    --cnt while cnt > 0
    return cnt

main()
```

When you run the above code, you will notice that the resolveTime (the time your code run into the callback function) is much later than 100ms from the beginTime.

So If we want to know when the Promise is actually resolved, HOW?

---

I want to know the exact time because I'm doing some profiling via logging. And I'm not able to modify the Promise p 's implementation when I'm doing some profiling outside of the black box.

So, Is there some function like promise.onUnderlyingConditionFulfilled(callback) , or any other way to make this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to know that time?

Comment: Actual !== predicted. No surprises.

Comment: @Bergi cause I'm doing some profiling via logging, I need to know when the http request is actually responsed, without influence of the other code.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I can't get your point... Sorry for my poor English skill

Comment: @luochen1990 For that, use the performance timing API. It gets you the timestamps of http requests without even having been active at the time.

Comment: @Bergi Any example about how "performance timing API" can solve this problem ?

Comment: @luochen1990 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_Timeline

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have a busy loop that apparently takes longer than your timer:

```
cnt = 10**9
--cnt while cnt > 0
```

Javascript in node.js is single threaded and event driven.  It can only do one thing at a time and it will finish the current thing it's doing before it can service the event posted by `setTimeout()`.  So, if your busy loop (or any other long running piece of Javascript code) takes longer than you've set your timer for, the timer will not be able to run until this other Javascript code is done.  "single threaded" means Javascript in node.js only does one thing at a time and it waits until one thing returns control back to the system before it can service the next event waiting to run.

So, here's the sequence of events in your code:

1. It calls the `setTimeout()` to schedule the timer callback for 100ms from now.
2. Then you go into your busy loop.
3. While it's in the busy loop, the `setTimeout()` timer fires inside of the JS implementation and it inserts an event into the Javascript event queue.  That event can't run at the moment because the JS interpreter is still running the busy loop.
4. Then eventually it finishes the busy loop and returns control back to the system.
5. When that is done, the JS interpreter then checks the event queue to see if any other events need servicing.  It finds the timer event and so it processes that and the `setTimeout()` callback is called.
6. That callback resolves the promise which triggers the `.then()` handler to get called.

Note: Because of Javascript's single threaded-ness and event-driven nature, timers in Javascript are not guaranteed to be called exactly when you schedule them.  They will execute as close to that as possible, but if other code is running at the time they fire or if their are lots of items in the event queue ahead of you, that code has to finish before the timer callback actually gets to execute.

> So If we want to know when the Promise is actually resolved, HOW?

The promise is resolved when your busy loop is done.  It's not resolved at exactly the 100ms point (because your busy loop apparently takes longer than 100ms to run).  If you wanted to know exactly when the promise was resolved, you would just log inside the `setTimeout()` callback right where you call `resolve()`.  That would tell you exactly when the promise was resolved though it will be pretty much the same as where you're logging now.  The cause of your delay is the busy loop.

---

Per your comments, it appears that you want to somehow measure exactly when `resolve()` is actually called in the Promise, but you say that you cannot modify the code in `getData()`.  You can't really do that directly.  As you already know, you can measure when the `.then()` handler gets called which will probably be no more than a couple ms after `resolve()` gets called.

You could replace the promise infrastructure with your own implementation and then you could instrument the `resolve()` callback directly, but replacing or hooking the promise implementation probably influences the timing of things even more than just measuring from the `.then()` handler.

So, it appears to me that you've just over-constrained the problem.  You want to measure when something inside of some code happens, but you don't allow any instrumentation inside that code.  That just leaves you with two choices:

1. Replace the promise implementation so you can instrument `resolve()` directly.
2. Measure when `.then()` is triggered.

The first option probably has a heisenberg uncertainty issue in that you've probably influenced the timing by more than you should if you replace or hook the promise implementation.

The second option measures an event that happens just slightly after the actual `.resolve()`.  Pick which one sounds closest to what you actually want.

Comment: …though of course the whole timeout callback and promise resolution process is delayed by the busy loop, not only the promise callback. I'd expect <1ms between the execution of the `setTimeout` callback and the `then` callback, so moving the `resolveTime` there shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Bergi - I'm not sure exactly what point you're trying to make.  I wasn't trying to say that there was somehow a big difference between when `resolve()` was called and when the `.then()` handler is called.  I modified my last two sentences to make sure that is clear.  My last paragraph was just trying to answer the literal question that was asked.  All the paragraphs that come before explain why it's delayed.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the clarification that moving it there will hardly alter the behaviour.

Comment: I want to know the exact time because I'm doing some profiling, and My question is about "HOW to get the correct time?", but NOT about "WHY this happend", I actually know why it happens and the above code is written to explain why. And I'm not able to modify the Promise p 's implementation when I'm doing some profiling outside of the black box.

Comment: @luochen1990 - You are asking how to measure when something in code you cannot modify happens.  You can't do that from plain Javascript.  When the `.then()` handler is called is as close as you can get and it will be within a ms or so.

Comment: @luochen1990 - Now that I'm back to my main computer, I've added some more to the end of my answer about measuring what you're asking for.

Comment: thanks for your patience, I think maybe reask my question like "Is there some function like promise.onUnderlyingConditionFulfilled(callback)? " is preciser, any idea about that?

Comment: @luochen1990 - I don't know what that last comment means at all.   Promises work by calling resolve when you want them to be fulfilled.  There is no mechanism for automatically fulfilling them when some condition changes.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think it is not a problem about hacking the implementation of `Promise`, but a problem about hacking NodeJS, what I want is some NodeJS builtin mechanism which runs in a subprocess independent of the JavaScript event loop, so that I can know the precise time when a HTTP response is actually received by the OS kernel.

Comment: @luochen1990 - So a month and a half after asking the question, you come back and tell us what the actual problem is.  Jeez.  Next time, please put the ACTUAL problem in the question.  What you're asking for might be available inside the native code of the event loop.  Or you might have to hack OS-level TCP and/or ethernet drivers to get it or perhaps you could use a multi-threaded proxy server to capture the data before the connection event gets to node.js.  This has absolutely nothing to do with the promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, when I realized the real problem, the problem is gone. When I ask the question, I'm not sure if there is some builtin mechanism there, and did some inaccurate simplification. And after read about all your answers and comments, and think deeper, I know that my expression is not clear enough, and now I can expression my problem more precisely.  I apologise for my late reply, and thank you for your patience :)